# Returning multiple variables using the overloaded << operator when reading a file

Tags: c++, methods, return, getline, fileinputstream

I have a peculiar situation in front of me. I've done too much processing of information within a method that I've no idea how to retrieve any of the data processed within it.

```
#include "Processing.h"
#include <sstream>
#include "vector.h"
#include "Data.h"



Processing::Processing()
{
  date = '0';

}

int maxlines = -1;

istream& operator>>(istream& input, Processing& D)
{
    vector<Data> v(maxlines);
    int count = 0;

    loop:
    int times = 1;

    maxlines++;
    while (!input.eof())
    {
        if (count < 2)
        {
            getline(input, D.title);

            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            stringstream ss;
            Data MC;

            switch (times)
            {
            case 1:
                getline(input, D.data, ',');
                ss << D.data;
                ss >> D.date;
                //v.push_back(D.date);
                ss >> D.time;
                ss >> D.ampm;
                break;
            case 2:
                getline(input, D.data, ',');
                ss << D.data;
                ss >> D.price;
                break;
            case 3:
                getline(input, D.data, ',');
                ss << D.data;
                ss >> D.volume;
                break;
            case 4:
                getline(input, D.data, ',');
                ss << D.data;
                ss >> D.insum;
                break;
            case 5:
                getline(input, D.condition);
                MC.set(D.date, D.time, D.ampm, D.price, D.volume, D.insum, D.condition);
                v.push(MC);
                goto loop;
            default:
                return input;
            }
            times++;
        }
    }
}

ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, const Processing & D )
{


    os  << D.header << '\n'
    << D.price << '\n'
    << D.volume << '\n';



  return os;
}
```

I know the code is messy but please bear with it, and I do understand that `eof` in a `while` loop is wrong. As I'm still a student, getting the code working is more of a priority. But of course, you can suggest alternatives to the `eof` while loop.

Now to start things off, as you can see, I had declared a vector and is intending to push the different data (`D.date`, `D.time`, etc) into it.

But from what I know, a method will destroy itself after returning it's value. And in this method, it returns only this "input" in which I had ignored.

How do I get all the data out from the input file I have and throw them into the different containers (`D.date`, `D.time`, etc) outside of the method?

Or

How do I return all the data I had processed in this method?

FYI:

Struct cannot be used here. I'm told specifically not to use struct.

Input file:

```
Course Of Sales
Time,Price ($),Volume,Value ($),Condition
10/10/2013 04:57:27 PM,5.81,5000,29050.00,LT XT
10/10/2013 04:48:05 PM,5.81,62728,364449.68,SX XT
10/10/2013 04:10:33 PM,.00,0,.00,
```

Note that the first two lines are ignored and goes into a container called D.header which wont be used.

Comment: Two things: First of all don't do e.g. `while (!input.eof())`, it will not work as you expect it to. The `eofbit` flag will not be set until *after* you try to read from beyond the end of the file. So this will loop once to many without you noticing. The other thing is that there are places where `goto` may be okay to use. Using `goto` as a loop is seldom, if ever, one of this places.

Comment: Acknowledged. The goto is just a stopgap measure to force the loop to work. I will take it out after the main bulk of the code is working.

Comment: I think what you REALLY want to do is copy the greater portions of your "functionality" into a different routine, and use the istream operator for the simple inputter it is supposed to be.

Comment: It would help if you tell us the format of the data you're parsing and what goes where. The definition of `Processing` too.

Comment: If you are reading into a `Processing` object, then everything you need should be in processing, and not stored anywhere else. Otherwise, why use `>>`?

Comment: jrok, input file edited in.

As for the definitions, it contains only the overloaded methods and the different declarations of the variables.

Comment: crashmstr, as you can see, I wanna store all of them in a vector and then outputting into a .txt file using the ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, const Processing & D ). But as the vector itself will be destroyed after returning, I won't be able to output anything out.